# Celery jobs not running on heroku (python/django app)

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I have a Django app setup with some scheduled tasks. The app is deployed on Heroku with Redis. The task runs if invoked synchronously in the console, or locally when I also have redis and celery running. However, the scheduled jobs are not running on Heroku.

My task:

```
@shared_task(name="send_emails")
def send_emails():
.....
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
# this is also used in manage.py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

# Get the base REDIS URL, default to redis' default
BASE_REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

app = Celery('my_app')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.broker_url = BASE_REDIS_URL

# this allows you to schedule items in the Django admin.
app.conf.beat_scheduler = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

# These are the scheduled jobs
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send_emails_crontab': {
        'task': 'send_emails',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=9, minute=0),
        'args': (),
    }
}
```

In Procfile:
`worker: celery -A my_app worker --beat -S django -l info`

I've spun up the worker with `heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a my-app`.
I can see the registered tasks under `[tasks]` in the worker logs.
However, the scheduled tasks are not running at their scheduled time. Calling `send_emails.delay()` in the production console does work.
How do I get the worker to stay alive and / or run the job at the scheduled time?

I have a workaround using a command and heroku scheduler. Just unsure if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on free demo, you should know that heroku server sleeps and if your scheduled task becomes due when your server is sleeping, it won't run.

Comment: This was the answer - paying $14 for a hobby setup fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh, thanks... ugahchymdy@gmail.com is my email. Please send me a message and let's talk.

Answer (score 0):

I share you any ideas.

1. Run console and get the datetime of Dyno. The Dyno use a localtime US.
2. The DynoFree sleeps each 30 minutes and only 450 hours/month.
3. Try change celery to BackgroundScheduler,
   you need add a script clock.py as:

   ```
    from myapp import myfunction
    from datetime import datetime
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
    from time import monotonic, sleep, ctime
    import os

    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    hour = int(os.environ.get("SEARCH_HOUR"))
    minutes = int(os.environ.get("SEARCH_MINUTES"))

    @sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=hour, minute = minutes)
    def scheduled_job():
        print('This job: Execute myfunction every at ', hour, ':', minutes)        
        #My function
        myfunction()

    sched.start(
   ```

)

In Procfile:

```
clock: python clock.py
```

and run:

```
heroku ps:scale clock=1 --app thenameapp
```

Regards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).